# Font setting getting over ridden in android

Tags: android, android-styles

I am trying to set up the font of my application by using styles.xml

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/AppText</item>
</style>

<style name="AppText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
</style>

<style name="SplashText" parent="@style/AppText">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/TextColour</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

The problem is when I change the font from the settings to comic sans or Helvetica (Galaxy SII supports these fonts) my application font also changes. I want my application to have the font I have set in styles.xml.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It Should be like this. Remove @style

```
<style name="SplashText" parent="AppText">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/TextColour</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This code block is the same as the one I pasted. No changes!!

Comment: How you are calling the style ? And The problem is coming in all device ? or in Samsung only ?